# message send to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, memory, nsmutablearray, memory-management

I am trying to sort memory problems in my program.

My program stops at the line:

```
 label.text = [[[[self.allData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1]objectAtIndex:1+[[self.measurments objectAtIndex:(i-1)]intValue]]objectAtIndex:1]stringValue];
```

whit mesage:

```
 Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT 
 ** -[CFNumber stringValue]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x859add0
```

I have property for allData and measurments

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *allData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *measurments;
```

and I defined allData as :

```
self.allData = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];

self.allData = [self GetTableOfLevel:TableLevel section:TableSection perent:0 array:self._backupData];
```

where GetTableOfLevel:TableLevel function return NSMutableArray.

after that I leave allData as it is, except i copy it as:

```
self.backupData = [[self.allData copy]autorelease];
```

Have any one any idea what it might go wrong?

---

I tried the advice and switch to ARC, but I have some problem whit downloaded library.

I have SBTableAlert which look like:

```
    //
//  --------------------------------------------
//  Copyright (C) 2011 by Simon Blommegård
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
//  of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
//  in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
//  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
//  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
//  furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
//  all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
//  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
//  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
//  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
//  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
//  OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
//  THE SOFTWARE.
//  --------------------------------------------
//
//  SBTableAlert.h
//  SBTableAlert
//
//  Created by Simon Blommegård on 2011-04-08.
//  Copyright 2011 Simon Blommegård. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define kTableCornerRadius 5.

typedef enum {
    SBTableAlertTypeSingleSelect, // dismiss alert with button index -1 and animated (default)
    SBTableAlertTypeMultipleSelct, // dismiss handled by user eg. [alert.view dismiss...];
} SBTableAlertType;

typedef enum {
    SBTableAlertStylePlain, // plain white BG and clear FG (default)
    SBTableAlertStyleApple, // same style as apple in the alertView for slecting wifi-network (Use SBTableAlertCell)
} SBTableAlertStyle;

// use this class if you would like to use the custom section headers by yourself
@interface SBTableViewSectionHeaderView : UIView {}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@end

@interface SBTableAlertCell : UITableViewCell {}
- (void)drawCellBackgroundView:(CGRect)r;
@end

@class SBTableAlert;

@protocol SBTableAlertDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

- (CGFloat)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableAlertCancel:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert;

- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

- (void)willPresentTableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert;
- (void)didPresentTableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert;

- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

@end

@protocol SBTableAlertDataSource <NSObject>
@required

- (UITableViewCell *)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSInteger)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

@optional

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert; // default 1
- (NSString *)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

@end

@interface SBTableAlert : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate> {}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *view;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic) SBTableAlertType type;
@property (nonatomic) SBTableAlertStyle style;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger maximumVisibleRows; // default 4, (nice in both orientations w/ rowHeigh == 40), if -1 is passed it will display the whole table.
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat rowHeight; // default 40, (default in UITableView == 44)

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SBTableAlertDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SBTableAlertDataSource> dataSource;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UITableViewDelegate> tableViewDelegate; // default self, (set other for more advanded use)
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UITableViewDataSource> tableViewDataSource; // default self, (set other for more advanded use)
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UIAlertViewDelegate> alertViewDelegate; // default self, (set other for more advanded use)

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelTitle messageFormat:(NSString *)message, ...;
+ (id)alertWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelTitle messageFormat:(NSString *)message, ...;

- (void)show;

@end


    //
//  --------------------------------------------
//  Copyright (C) 2011 by Simon Blommegård
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
//  of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
//  in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
//  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
//  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
//  furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
//  all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
//  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
//  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
//  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
//  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
//  OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
//  THE SOFTWARE.
//  --------------------------------------------
//
//  SBTableAlert.m
//  SBTableAlert
//
//  Created by Simon Blommegård on 2011-04-08.
//  Copyright 2011 Simon Blommegård. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SBTableAlert.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface SBTableViewTopShadowView : UIView {}
@end

@implementation SBTableViewTopShadowView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw top shadow
    CGFloat colors [] = { 
        0, 0, 0, 0.4,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
    };

    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMinY(self.bounds));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), 8);

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;
}

@end

@interface SBTableView : UITableView {}
@property (nonatomic) SBTableAlertStyle alertStyle;
@end

@implementation SBTableView

@synthesize alertStyle=_alertStyle;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (_alertStyle == SBTableAlertStyleApple) {
        // Draw background gradient
        CGFloat colors [] = { 
            0.922, 0.925, 0.933, 1,
            0.749, 0.753, 0.761, 1,
        };

        CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

        CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMinY(self.bounds));
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(self.bounds));

        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;
    }

    [super drawRect:rect];
}

@end

@interface SBTableAlertCellBackgroundView : UIView
@end

@implementation SBTableAlertCellBackgroundView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)r {
    [(SBTableAlertCell *)[self superview] drawCellBackgroundView:r];
}

@end

@implementation SBTableViewSectionHeaderView
@synthesize title=_title;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero])) {
        [self setTitle:title];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.165 green:0.224 blue:0.376 alpha:0.85]];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self setTitle:nil];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.8] set];
    [_title drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 4) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];  
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    [_title drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 5) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.5);

    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.35] set];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, 0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.35] set];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

@end

@interface SBTableAlertCell ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) SBTableAlertCellBackgroundView *cellBackgroundView;
@end

@implementation SBTableAlertCell
@synthesize cellBackgroundView = _cellBackgroundView;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, self.contentView.bounds.size.height);

        _cellBackgroundView = [[SBTableAlertCellBackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [_cellBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [_cellBackgroundView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
        [self setBackgroundView:_cellBackgroundView];
        [_cellBackgroundView release];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    float editingOffset = 0.;
    if (self.editing)
        editingOffset = -self.contentView.frame.origin.x;

    _cellBackgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(editingOffset,
                                                                            _cellBackgroundView.frame.origin.y,
                                                                            self.frame.size.width - editingOffset,
                                                                            _cellBackgroundView.frame.size.height);

    [self.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.detailTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setNeedsDisplay {
    [super setNeedsDisplay];
    [_cellBackgroundView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawCellBackgroundView:(CGRect)r {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.5);

    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.8] set];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, 0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.35] set];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

@end

@interface SBTableAlert ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) SBTableViewTopShadowView *shadow;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL presented;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelTitle messageFormat:(NSString *)format args:(va_list)args;
- (void)increaseHeightBy:(CGFloat)delta;
- (void)layout;

@end

@implementation SBTableAlert

@synthesize view=_alertView;
@synthesize tableView=_tableView;
@synthesize type=_type;
@synthesize style=_style;
@synthesize maximumVisibleRows=_maximumVisibleRows;
@synthesize rowHeight=_rowHeight;

@synthesize delegate=_delegate;
@synthesize dataSource=_dataSource;

@dynamic tableViewDelegate;
@dynamic tableViewDataSource;
@dynamic alertViewDelegate;

@synthesize shadow = _shadow;
@synthesize presented = _presented;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelTitle messageFormat:(NSString *)format args:(va_list)args {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSString *message = format ? [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args] autorelease] : nil;

        _alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle otherButtonTitles:nil];

        _maximumVisibleRows = 4;
        _rowHeight = 40.;

        _tableView = [[SBTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];

        [_tableView setDelegate:self];
        [_tableView setDataSource:self];
        [_tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [_tableView setRowHeight:_rowHeight];
        [_tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [_tableView.layer setCornerRadius:kTableCornerRadius];

        [_alertView addSubview:_tableView];

        _shadow = [[SBTableViewTopShadowView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [_shadow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [_shadow setHidden:YES];
        [_shadow.layer setCornerRadius:kTableCornerRadius];
        [_shadow.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

        [_alertView addSubview:_shadow];
        [_alertView bringSubviewToFront:_shadow];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(layoutAfterSomeTime) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelTitle messageFormat:(NSString *)message, ... {
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, message);
    self = [self initWithTitle:title cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle messageFormat:message args:list];
    va_end(list);
    return self;
}

+ (id)alertWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelTitle messageFormat:(NSString *)message, ... {
    return [[[SBTableAlert alloc] initWithTitle:title cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle messageFormat:message] autorelease];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self setTableView:nil];
    [self setView:nil];

    [self setShadow:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -

- (void)show {
    [_tableView reloadData];
    [_alertView show];
}

#pragma mark - Properties

- (void)setStyle:(SBTableAlertStyle)style {
    if (style == SBTableAlertStyleApple) {
        [_tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
        [(SBTableView *)_tableView setAlertStyle:SBTableAlertStyleApple];
        [_shadow setHidden:NO];
    } else if (style == SBTableAlertStylePlain) {
        [_tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
        [(SBTableView *)_tableView setAlertStyle:SBTableAlertStylePlain];
        [_shadow setHidden:YES];
    }
    _style = style;
}

- (id<UITableViewDelegate>)tableViewDelegate {
    return _tableView.delegate;
}

- (void)setTableViewDelegate:(id<UITableViewDelegate>)tableViewDelegate {
    [_tableView setDelegate:tableViewDelegate];
}

- (id<UITableViewDataSource>)tableViewDataSource {
    return _tableView.dataSource;
}

- (void)setTableViewDataSource:(id<UITableViewDataSource>)tableViewDataSource {
    [_tableView setDataSource:tableViewDataSource];
}

- (id<UIAlertViewDelegate>)alertViewDelegate {
    return _alertView.delegate;
}

- (void)setAlertViewDelegate:(id<UIAlertViewDelegate>)alertViewDelegate {
    [_alertView setDelegate:alertViewDelegate];
}


#pragma mark - Private

- (void)increaseHeightBy:(CGFloat)delta {
    CGPoint c = _alertView.center;
    CGRect r = _alertView.frame;
    r.size.height += delta;
    _alertView.frame = r;
    _alertView.center = c;
    _alertView.frame = CGRectIntegral(_alertView.frame);

    for(UIView *subview in [_alertView subviews]) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
            CGRect frame = subview.frame;
            frame.origin.y += delta;
            subview.frame = frame;
        }
    }
}


- (void)layout {
    CGFloat height = 0.;
    NSInteger rows = 0;
    for (NSInteger section = 0; section < [_tableView numberOfSections]; section++) {
        for (NSInteger row = 0; row < [_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++) {
            height += [_tableView.delegate tableView:_tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
            rows ++;
        }
    }

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat avgRowHeight = height / rows;
    CGFloat resultHeigh;

    if(height > screenRect.size.height) {
        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
            resultHeigh = screenRect.size.height - _alertView.frame.size.height - 65.;
        else
            resultHeigh = screenRect.size.width - _alertView.frame.size.height - 65.;
    }
    else if (_maximumVisibleRows == -1 || rows <= _maximumVisibleRows)
        resultHeigh = _tableView.contentSize.height;
    else
        resultHeigh = (avgRowHeight * _maximumVisibleRows);

    [self increaseHeightBy:resultHeigh];


    [_tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(12,
                                                                    _alertView.frame.size.height - resultHeigh - 65,
                                                                    _alertView.frame.size.width - 24,
                                                                    resultHeigh)];

    [_shadow setFrame:CGRectMake(_tableView.frame.origin.x,
                                                             _tableView.frame.origin.y,
                                                             _tableView.frame.size.width,
                                                             8)];
}

- (void)layoutAfterSomeTime{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(layout) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableAlert:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)])
        return [_delegate tableAlert:self heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return _rowHeight;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (_type == SBTableAlertTypeSingleSelect)
        [_alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableAlert:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)])
        [_delegate tableAlert:self didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([_dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(tableAlert:titleForHeaderInSection:)]) {
        NSString *title = [_dataSource tableAlert:self titleForHeaderInSection:section];
        if (!title)
            return nil;

        return [[[SBTableViewSectionHeaderView alloc] initWithTitle:title] autorelease];
    }

    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([self tableView:tableView viewForHeaderInSection:section])
        return 25.;
    return 0.;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    return [_dataSource tableAlert:self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_dataSource tableAlert:self numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if ([_dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(numberOfSectionsInTableAlert:)])
        return [_dataSource numberOfSectionsInTableAlert:self];

    return 1;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIAlertViewDelegate

- (void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableAlertCancel:)])
        [_delegate tableAlertCancel:self];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableAlert:clickedButtonAtIndex:)])
        [_delegate tableAlert:self clickedButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex];
}

- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    if (!_presented)
        [self layout];
    _presented = YES;
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(willPresentTableAlert:)])
        [_delegate willPresentTableAlert:self];
}
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didPresentTableAlert:)])
        [_delegate didPresentTableAlert:self];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableAlert:willDismissWithButtonIndex:)])
        [_delegate tableAlert:self willDismissWithButtonIndex:buttonIndex];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    _presented = NO;
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableAlert:didDismissWithButtonIndex:)])
        [_delegate tableAlert:self didDismissWithButtonIndex:buttonIndex];
}

@end
```

I put -fno-objc-arc flag on it, but when I tried open it it gave me an

```
*** -[SBTableAlert tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x816b8c0
```

error

I open it as :

```
SBTableAlert   *alert;
    alert   = [[SBTableAlert alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"servers", nil) cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"cancel", nil) messageFormat:nil];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert setDataSource:self];
    [alert.view setTag:1];

    [alert show];
```

Anyone know how to deal with it?

Comment: Just a quick observation... There is no need to alloc `self.allData` if `GetTableOfLevel` returns an `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Can you show the code of `GetTableOfLevel`?

Comment: it is too long for comment, but I think it must me bug some where else , because if I printed out after line where alldata is fill it printed fine, but if I run same print in cellForRowAtIndexPath it gave me this error message.

Comment: print is:    for (int i = 0;i< [self.allData count]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<[[self.allData objectAtIndex:i]count]; j++) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [[[self.allData objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j]objectAtIndex:1]);
        }
    }

Comment: @Marko you can edit your question to include the method implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holy run-on sentence, Batman!  Try breaking up those nested method calls into multiple lines as it'll make the code more readable.

Given that the final expression was the one generating the error message, it looks like an object in one of your arrays -- a leaf node / data object -- was over-released.

Thus, the fault lies at whatever creates the array.

BTW:   Methods should always start with lower case letters and should never be prefixed with `get`.   Thus, that method would be `tableFromLevel:section:parent:array:` or something similar.   By convention, `get*` as a prefix is reserved for methods that return stuff by reference.  Accessors are not prefixed with `get`, either.

Also and indicated in the comments, there is no need to create an empty array, assign it to self.allData and then immediately overwrite it.  Not a leak because of the `autorelease`, but no point in doing that.

---

First, build and analyze your code.   Fix Anything that it complains about.

Next, if the crash is still happening, use the Allocations instrument and turn on Zombie detection.  It should allow you to see the retains/releases sent to the object that is crashing.

Comment: I know it may be sound stupid, but I am quite new at objectiv-c. Why method can't ce called whit prefix get?

Comment: and how to detect when the object was released?

Comment: @marko it is not that it can't be named that way, but the standard coding practice in Obj-c is to not name getters with a "get" prefix.

Comment: Just a short note. If you are not so familiar with objective-c switch ARC (during project creation) on or convert your project. It helps a lot with object allocation/deallocation.

Comment: hi, thanks for your advice. I will look up for ARC. Did ARC slows down your project? And if I understand correctly it is just need to remove all release/retain/autorelease/dealloc from code and it should work.

Comment: ARC is, in many cases, faster.   It involves more than just removal of the methods you mention, but that removal is most of the work.  There is a built in ARC migration tool that'll identify problems in your code that prevent use of ARC.   Every time I've used it on existing projects, it has identified serious bugs.